# UniqueList Class in VBA

Tags: sorting, vba, collections, binary-search

I often find myself abusing dictionary objects just for the exist method like this,

```
For Each x in Something
    If Not dict.Exists(x) Then dict.Add x, False 
Next x
```

Then just exploit the `.Exists(x)` method.  It happens often enough that I thought it merited it's own class.

Instead of composing `Scripting.Dictionary`, I decided to just maintain a sorted list of unique items.  Usage is simple; unique items are inserted into the collection sorted.  Non-unique items are not added.

### Attributes

Let's just get this out of the way.  Attribute `VB_PredeclaredId` must be set to `True` and `NewEnum` allows the class to be iterable.  I still haven't found a way to replicate this using an array instead of a collection.  With an array I could offload some of my code to my standard library, but then this wouldn't be standalone or portable.

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1
END
Attribute VB_Name = "UniqueList"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Option Explicit

Private list As Collection

Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set list = New Collection
End Sub
Public sub Class_Terminate()
    Set list = Nothing
End Sub
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4

    Set NewEnum = list.[_NewEnum]

End Property
```

### Data Manipulation

```
Public Sub Add(ByVal element As Variant)

    If IsEmpty Then

        list.Add element
        Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim index As Long
    index = LocateIndex(element)

    If (list(index) > element) Then
        list.Add element, Before:=index
    ElseIf list(index) < element Then
        list.Add element, After:=index
    End If

End Sub
Public Sub Merge(ByVal list_ As Variant)

    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In list_
        Add element
    Next element

End Sub
Public Sub Remove(ByVal element As Variant)

    Dim index As Long
    index = LocateIndex(element)

    If (list(index) = element) Then list.Remove index

End Sub
Public Sub Clear()

    Set list = Nothing
    Set list = New Collection

End Sub
```

### Introspection

Note I don't implement an `Item(x)` method.  I don't want users to be able to scramble the data.

```
Public Function Exists(ByVal element As Variant) As Boolean
    Exists = (element = list(LocateIndex(element)))
End Function
Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = list.Count
End Function
Public Function IsEmpty() As Boolean
    IsEmpty = (Count = 0)
End Function
```

### Searching

The only private method is a binary search that returns where the element is or where it should be.

```
Private Function LocateIndex(ByVal element As Variant) As Long

    Dim upper As Long
    upper = Count

    Dim lower As Long
    lower = 1

    While lower < upper

        Dim middle As Long
        middle = (lower + upper) \ 2

        If list(middle) >= element Then
            upper = middle
        Else
            lower = middle + 1
        End If

    Wend

    LocateIndex = upper

End Function
```

Comment: You should really come to [the 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) sometime. I really enjoy seeing your questions.

Comment: I think at this point it might be worth building a [**trie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Note I don't implement an Item(x) method. I don't want users to be able to scramble the data.*

Ok. But then why expose a `NewEnum` to enable `For Each` loops? Without an `Item` getter (with `VB_UserMemId` set to `0` to identify the type's *default property*), it's not clear how a `For Each` loop might work. An `Item` property won't let the client code *scramble* the data if you don't implement a setter for it.

**Searching**

I like the idea, I like the implementation, ..but I would have called if `IndexOf`. Just a couple of points:

> ```
> If list(middle) >= element Then
> ```

If `list` is empty, this method explodes. You may want to consider raising a custom error in this case, and gracefully handle an empty collection in the public methods.

Also I like that you're declaring variables close to their usage, but this:

> ```
> While lower < upper
>
>     Dim middle As Long
>     middle = (lower + upper) \ 2
> ```

Is potentially confusing. Consider moving the declaration outside the loop. It's not like the `While` block defined a scope anyway!

```
Dim middle As Long
While lower < upper

    middle = (lower + upper) \ 2
```

---

The binary search and sorted nature of this `UniqueList` are nice, but given the goal:

> *I often find myself abusing dictionary objects just for the exist method*

You wrote that code to implement your own `Exists` method, and you're using `Variant` which tells me you're using it for more than just `Integer` items.

**Objects**

It would have been nice to handle object items, since a `Variant` can also be an `Object`; your code is silent about how objects are dealt with.

Actually, if I read your code correctly, this `UniqueList` will happily allow me to `Add` a `New ADODB.Connection`, **and then will blow up when I try to add a 2nd item**... or if I try to remove it with the `Remove` method - the `Clear` method will work.

Because we can't override operators (like `>=`) in VBA, I'd handle objects with a \$O(n)\$ linear search that performs an equality check on each `IsObject(item)` item until it finds the existing object reference (or not). You could mitigate this a little, by introducing an `IComparable` interface that custom classes could implement, and then you could call `comparable.CompareTo(element)` and have custom classes that could be handled with a binary search, if they specify how they compare to items of a given type.

There should also be a mechanism for ensuring all items are of the same type: as it stands I could add an `Integer`, a `Date`, a `Short` and a `Long` to an instance of a `UniqueList`, and VBA would find a way to sort them, and that's implicit and not pretty.

I think your class is more like some kind of a `SortedList<T>` (to borrow from [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) notation), that doesn't allow duplicates: all items in a `SortedList<T>` are of type `T`, whatever that type is.

Answer (score 4):

Just a couple of notes. The biggest of which is that I think you've misunderstood what `VB_PredeclaredId` does. It [creates a default instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199159.aspx) of the class. Which allows you to do things like this

```
UniqueList.Add someItem
```

Without declaring and setting a new instance of the class. It's a cool feature, but it's not what allows the list to be iterable and you don't need it here. The `[_NewEnum]` is what allows the `For Each` syntax.

The `Clear` method doesn't need to `Set list = Nothing`. Drop that line and just set it to a new instance of `Collection`.

Lastly, I find it really odd that you have a list with no way to get an element back out of the list. We can add and remove items, but not retrieve them. I would rethink implementing an `Item` method.